# when converting a string to a string array during splitting, it produces an undesired output

Tags: java, arrays, string, printing, split

When i try to split a String "Element" into a String array, and then print out the result i get an output which i don't understand. My code is as follows:

```
String element = mapArray.get(i);
elementSplit = element.split("(?!^)");
System.out.println(elementSplit);
```

And the output produced when i print the String Array is:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@3dee2310
```

Could someone please advise, as i do not know why it is printing this output.

Thanks very much

Comment: Use `Arrays#toString()` method to print an array.

Comment: That could be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elementSplit));
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to speed You should use `toCharArray` method instead of `split("(?!^)")`  and in order to print array you should use `Arrays.toString` method

```
String element = mapArray.get(i);
elementSplit = element.toCharArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(elementSplit));
```